# binding dropdownlist by another dropdownlist in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new with mvc and I have 2 dropdownlists and I need to bind second one by first one using mvc 3..

Code sample

```
@<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Brands", Model.Brands, "Select Brand", New With {.style = "width:150px;"})
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Models", Model.Models, "Select Model", New With {.style = "width:150px;"})
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Devices", Model.Devices, "Select Device", New With {.style = "width:150px;"})
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("Systems", Model.Systems, "Select System", New With {.style = "width:150px;"})
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to fill Models by Brands and Fill Devices by Models.
any help please..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.Model, new SelectList( LookupUtils.GetModelsList(Model.Brand), "Value", "Text", Model.Model))
```

LookupUtils is a static class have:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetModelsList(int brand)
{
    var dataContext = new YourDataContext(  );
    var data = dataContext.GetModelsFn(brand).ToList();

    var result = ( from res in data
                   select new SelectListItem()
                              {
                                  Text = res.modelName,
                                  Value = res.modelId.ToString()
                              } ).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

For dynamicly update some dropdown lists, you should use jQuery-Collapse plugin: http://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Collapse/